# How to subscribe to a normal function as an Observable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, observable, mean-stack

I have a function that returns an object.

```
           getUserState(): UserState {
              return this.userState;
           }
```

I am storing the above function result in an observable as follows:

```
       username$: Observable<UserState[]>;

       constructor(private userService:UserStateService) {}

       ngOnInit(): void {
            this.username$ = this.userService.getUserState().map(data => 
            {
              this.username$ = data;
            }) 
      }
```

Here I am getting the error:

```
        Property 'map' does not exist on type 'UserState'.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The function returns a UserState object, which apparently doesn't have a map property. For that matter, neither does an Observable in RxJS 6. Your ngOnInit doesn't make any sense, are you trying to set `this.username$` to the outer value or the inner value? If you just want to create an observable of a single value, it's `of(value)`.

Comment: `getUserState().pipe(map(...))`

Comment: @Reactgular again, that method *doesn't return an observable*

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, if you look at the function return type than you are right, but honestly a service that doesn't return an observable in Angular is an anti-pattern and so I'm going to assume the OP isn't just making **one** mistake here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First return an actual observable:

```
getUserState(): Observable<UserState> {
  return of(this.userState);
}
```

Second you don't need map maybe you could use share or shareReplay

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.username$ = this.userService.getUserState().pipe(share());
}
```

third i suppose you are using it somewhere in template

```
{{ username$ | async | json }}
```

and if not just subscribe like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription = this.userService.getUserState().subscribe((state: UserState) => ...);
}
ngOndestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // clean up after yourself
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try importing 'map' operator.

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'